# Error while trying to create a new edmx file - VS 2013 , Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

As per my requirement i need to create a `edmx` file and establish a  connection to `sql server` thats residing in a  remote server and am following the VS 2013 , and using wizard model am trying to connect to DB.

But its throwing the error:
what am I missing, do i need set any settings / some installables?
Firstly i am getting the `sqlclr types` error, so i installed the same and other error was `sharedmanagementobjects` error, so i installed that `msi` as well.

my sql server is SQL SERVER 2012 STD - SP2,VERSION NUMBER : 11.0.5058

> Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:03.2592313.
>   Generating the model took 00:00:03.1761556.
>   Could not save the XML to the configuration file 'D:\PoCSolutions\EDMXTEST_WINFORMS1\EDMXTEST_WINFORMS1\App.config' because of the error 'Access to the path 'D:\PoCSolutions\EDMXTEST_WINFORMS1\EDMXTEST_WINFORMS1\App.config' is denied.'.
>   Unable to update the App.Config file because of the following exception: 'Access to the path 'D:\PoCSolutions\EDMXTEST_WINFORMS1\EDMXTEST_WINFORMS1\App.config' is denied.'
>   Writing the .edmx file took 00:00:00.0009981.

I am getting this error when trying to create a new `.edmx` file using VS 2013 with Entity Framework 5.0

[acess-denied-edmx-5.0-VS2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k9Kg.png)
[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: what am i missing? why i am getting the error?

Comment: I'm guessing that you've checked the location exists and that you have the relevant permissions?